# LiveCharts Columchart in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, livecharts

I have just started using LiveCharts in VB.NET. I've searched extensively but were unable to find how I can visualize a query result in my Cartesian Barchart.

My query results are the following:

```
>Week | Amount
>1    | 200
>2    | 150
>3    | 225
>4    | 175
```

The query result is stored inside a datatable.

So far I got this code in XAML to create the chart:

```
        <Wpf:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Left">
            <Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <Wpf:Axis Title="Week" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></Wpf:Axis>
            </Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <Wpf:Axis Title="Amount" LabelFormatter="{Binding AvaiAmount}"></Wpf:Axis>
            </Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        </Wpf:CartesianChart>
```

So what I need is VB.NET code to get my query result to show inside the CartesianChart. I'm rather new to VB.NET/LiveCharts and have no clue on what I need to do.. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The same way that you have put your X-Axis Labels in a (I assume) List, you can also put your Y-Values in a List. You only need to take care, that they are in the correct order. Then you define a `ColumnSeries` for your chart,  like this:

```
<Wpf:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Left">
    <Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <Wpf:Axis Title="Week" Labels="{Binding Labels}" />
    </Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>

    <Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <Wpf:Axis Title="Amount" LabelFormatter="{Binding AvaiAmount}" />
    </Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisY>

    <Wpf:ColumnSeries Name="cs"
                      Values = {Binding *YourValuesList*} />
</Wpf:CartesianChart>
```

===============

**Edit**

If I assum that you have a class like this:

```
Public Class WeekAmount
    Public Property Week As Integer
    Public Property Amount As Integer
End Class
```

And you have a list of this class (`ListOfWeekAmount`) in your datatable, then:

```
Dim ListOfAmounts = New List(Of Integer)
For Each item In ListOfWeekAmount
    ListOfAmounts.Add(item.Amount)
Next
```

Then:

```
<Wpf:ColumnSeries Name="cs"
                  Values = {Binding ListOfAmounts} />
```

Comment: And how do I add values in there thorugh my VB.NET code?

Comment: What is the type of your collection which results from your query? How do you make the List for the Weeks? Without knowing your collection, It's hard to say how you should make your `Values` collection

Comment: I execute a query and store it inside a datatable as shown in the original question.

Comment: My preview screen turns white whenever I add this piece of code to my XAML: (Sorry don't know how to format..)
    <lvc:ColumnSeries Name="cs"
                          Values = {Binding *YourValuesList*} />

Comment: Replace lvc with Wpf. Was a typo